# Exclude settings from a contrib module on export

Tags: drush, configuration, importing-exporting, 9

I've two environment, **dev** and **staging**. I'm using the [ReCaptcha module](https://www.drupal.org/project/recaptcha).

In the developpement environment, I have some api keys a other config which until now, are exported thanks to `drush cex` inside the *recaptcha.settings* file

```
site_key: mysite_key
secret_key: mysite_secret
verify_hostname: false
use_globally: false
widget:
  theme: dark
  type: image
  size: ''
  tabindex: 0
  noscript: false
_core:
  default_config_hash: mydefault_hash
langcode: fr
```

If I update my staging files website, the config from the development is imported with `drush cim`.

How can I, without another module, prevent this ?

In my *settings.local.dev.php*, I've added this line and ran `drush cex` :

```
$settings['config_exclude_modules'] = ['recaptcha'];
```

And it gave me this result

[image]

The config is completly deleted, but I'd like to keep all the config but not the *site_key / secret_key* (such as *theme* etc...)

I wish I could have a config for the development and the staging separetly, but still using drush commands.

Comment: You don't need to mess around with exports here, your secret key should never be in the codebase anyway. Use a [config override](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/configuration-api/configuration-override-system) in settings.php instead, much simpler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to exclude the API keys from export; instead, you can set them in code, and then it doesn't matter what gets exported. (...probably.  Some modules will not work with this approach.)

You can override config directly in `settings.php`.

Here's an example with Swiftmailer module taken from one of my sites.

**swiftmailer.transport.yml**

```
transport: smtp
smtp_host: smtp.example.com
smtp_port: 465
smtp_encryption: ssl
smtp_credential_provider: swiftmailer
smtp_credentials:
  swiftmailer:
    username: ''
    password: ''
sendmail_path: /usr/sbin/sendmail
sendmail_mode: bs
spool_directory: ''
_core:
  default_config_hash: RSNbRD3ekSaZoE19f3eHhm93gKOcD2PtmaAVmV3XMes
langcode: ja
```

Now I want to use a different API key for dev + production.  So, in `settings.php`, I set the config manually:

```
  $config['swiftmailer.transport']['smtp_credentials']['swiftmailer']['username'] = 'apikey';
  $config['swiftmailer.transport']['smtp_credentials']['swiftmailer']['password'] = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP'
```

In my case I'm using a switch to detect an environment variable (live, test, dev, etc.) because that's how the host Pantheon does it, but you can do the same thing with `settings.local.dev.php` files.

Config in `settings.php` will never be exported; drush will ignore it.  However, Drupal will always prioritize config set in code over `.yml` files.  As a result, if you need to change this, you will have to update the code itself; you won't be able to make changes from the UI anymore.

Also note that it is a potential security issue to check API keys into version control like this.

The [Config Override module](https://www.drupal.org/project/config_override) adds a warning to admin screens that reminds you that you are overriding values in code.

If security is a concern, there's the [Lockr](https://www.drupal.org/project/lockr) module, which was built specifically to handle the use case of juggling API keys, but you have to pay for that.

Comment: This is tricky, because my client will probably change the key one day or another (my question is more global than only one module in fact), so in this case, I don't think doing it by the code is the best approach...  But if I end up by doing by the code, if I understand well, I have to add this `$config['recaptcha.settings']['site_key'] = "mycustomky";` inside *settings.local.dev.php* ?

Comment: @mt.i.1 Yes, that looks correct.

Comment: It's working well on front, is it possible to "link" key in the database so that it appears in the backend ? Those fields are required, and I can't submit the form to save the other settings

Comment: @mt.i.1 You can use the production field value or a dummy field value (a bad API key that validates) to allow you to save the config.

Comment: If you don't want to save passwords and API keys in the active config (where they will be exported as YAML and exposed in the code repo in plaintext) or in a settings file (also exposed in the code repo as plaintext) you can store these values in a `secrets.php` file, unique per environment, which can be sourced by `settings.php` or `settings.local.php`.

Comment: Yes, I've endend up by doing something like that !